# AngularStrap Typeahead randomly selects the display value instead of model value

Tags: angularjs, angular-strap

I am using AngularStrap's Typeahead directive in several dropdowns and sometimes, the display value shows up as the selected value.

For example, if I want to show just the number as the selected value in the input field, sometimes both the number and the description are selected. Here is the relevant code :

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" 
        bs-typeahead
        bs-options="x.num as (x.num > 0 ? x.num + '. ' + x.Description :  '')for x 
                   in crc.xList | orderBy: 'x.num'" 
        data-autoSelect="true"
        data-limit="15"
        ng-model="crc.newNum"
        ng-model-options="{ debounce: 500 }"
        ng-change="crc.getNumInfo(false, true)" />
```

Any help would be appreciated - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because of `(x.num > 0 ? x.num + '. ' + x.Description :  '')`, I think angular replaces the empty string when `x.num` is 0 to the value, could you try to do `(x.num > 0 ? x.num + '. ' + x.Description :  'test')` instead and see if it fixes it ?

Comment: I tried your suggestion but that's not it - still see the issue.